# initialize array size from another array value

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

const int vals[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; 

int newArray[ vals[2] ]; //"error: array bound is not an integer constant"

int main(){
    return vals[2];
}

//returns 2 if erroneous line is removed
```

Why doesn't this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++ compiler can only allocate an array with a size known at compile time.  If you want to allocated a variable size piece of memory, use the `new` operator.

Comment: or even better yet, `std::vector`.

Comment: Looks like an answer to some other question to me

Answer (score 12):

Unfortunately you can't do that in standard C++ because `vals[2]` is not a constant expression! In the coming standard you would have `constexpr`(implemented in g++ 4.6) to request compile-time evaluation easily:

```
#include<iostream> 
using namespace std; 

constexpr int vals[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; 

int newArray[ vals[2] ]; // vals[2] is a constant expression now!

int main(){
    return vals[2];
}
```

Comment: The first sentence should now be "You *can* do that in standard C++ (ever since C++11); you only could not do it in C++03 or earlier" (or something like that), if I understand correctly.

Answer (score 8):

It's possible that the value of a `const` expression is not even known at compile time. For example, you can initialize a constant with something returned from a function, like

```
const int size = rand(); // random size
```

So it is not *that constant* as you might think