# array size and const

Tags: c++, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [initialize array size from another array value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589463/initialize-array-size-from-another-array-value)

**in C++**

```
const int a[]={1,2,3,4,5}; 
int b[a[2]]; 

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The code is giving error in line 2; 
However, if it is something like below it gives no error after compilation:

```
const int a=3; 
int b[a]; 

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Why is that? however if i define array b inside main it is alright in both the cases...

Comment: Select all your code and click the curly-braces button at the top of the code window in order to format it correctly. Also note that there is a **preview** below the question form, so you can see if your question is actually readable before posting it.

Comment: @Anon thnx i will do it next time onwards..

Comment: This same question was asked, almost identically, recently.

Comment: It would help if you provide the link for the question..

Comment: @Beta: If I knew I would. The point was to say that if anyone is up for it, they could search for it. I'm looking tentatively.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in C++ array sizes must be *constant expressions*, not just constant data.  Array data, even though const, is not a constant expression.

Second version IS a constant expression.

Comment: You may tell the OP also how can he make a dynamic array(using a variable size)...

Comment: if i define array b inside main then it don't give any error.please explain...

Comment: @prp: It is an error even if you define it "inside main". If your compiler does not report an error, it must be a non-standard language extension implemented by your compiler. I.e. your compiler supports local arrays with non-constant size. Nevertheless, C++ does not allow this even for local arrays.

Comment: why first one is a constant data and not an constant expression if it value remains constant at compile as well run time..

Comment: @algo-geeks: See [this answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4589628/4958) -- in C++11 you can say "constexpr" to make the compiler accept that a[2] really is a constant expression.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to make a variable-sized array. To do this, one must use pointers.

**POINTERS**

Normally, you would declare an array like this:

```
char a[4];
```

An array must be a constant size. It cannot change. How can we make the size variable? Like this.

```
char* a = new char[length];
```

What does this do? Normally, when you declare an array of a specific size, it is declared on the stack. What this code does, however, is instead allocate memory on the heap.

```
char a[4]; // This is created at compile time
char* a = new char[length]; // This is created at run time
```

You create a pointer to an address where you can declare and assign values to your array, all in a safe memory space.

Comment: No, we should use `std::vector` instead of bug-prone manual memory management.