# C++ Declare array whose size value from const array

Tags: c++, arrays, constants, constexpr, compile-time-constant

I'm trying to define a stack c-style array whose size is taken from const array and is known in compile-time.

```c
const int size[2]={100, 100};
int ar[size[0]]; //error: expression must have a constant value
```

It fails. How it can be fixed?

Comment: It works with g++4.4. It works also on [ideone](http://ideone.com/nfyLOs)

Comment: if you know the size at compile time you can always stick that in as the array size

Comment: @cpp: That's because GCC supports C-style variable-length arrays as a non-standard extension.

Answer (score 3):

*"array whose size is taken from const array and is known in **compile-time**"*

With C++11 you can have :

`constexpr int size[2]={100, 100}; // size[0] is Compile-time constant`

Use `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` to compile

Comment: @cpp: No it doesn't. It works with a hybrid of C++98 and C99 that supports variable-length arrays, but in standard C++ you need `constexpr` to use array elements as compile-time constants - and that wasn't available before 2011.

Answer (score 2):

Some options (with varying degrees of popularity):

1. Use constexpr (not supported in Visual Studio)
2. Use a Vector
3. Use dynamic allocation
4. Use a `const int` (C99 or newer or C++)
5. Use an `enum`
6. Use a MACRO to define the size (since it's known at compile time)

Comment: 1. constexpr could be a the best solution but it is not supported in Visual Studio 2010

2.3. Use a Vector/Use dynamic allocation -- this is not what I need

4. Use a MACRO / define - is not better than just using consts

Comment: Since you're using C++ you can do that, this is also possible if using a modern C compiler (C99 or newer - this will technically be a variable length array) but will not work on MSVC if you compile the code as C code.

Answer (score 1):

> C++ array sizes must be constant expressions, not just constant data.
>   Array data, even though const, is not a constant expression.

[array size and const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720304/array-size-and-const)